# delete happens before opening a modal with confirmation to delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have made a dialog where confirmation is asked to delete a log. But I am having problem when deleting the log. When i click on delete, the log gets deleted instead of opening a modal where user is asked if they are sure to delete or not. If they are ready to delete, they will click on delete button and then the log should delete. In my case the delete is happening before opening a modal. What have i done wrong?

```
handleDelete(key) {
  this.setState({ show: true });
  const logDeleteConfirmation = (
    <DeleteConfirmation
      hideDialog={this.props.hideDialog}
      logKey={key}
      onDelete={this.props.deleteLog(key)}
    />
  );
  this.props.showDialog(logDeleteConfirmation);
}


render() {
  return(
  <div className="col-md-6 text-right">
    <a
      className="text-danger"
      onClick={() => this.handleDelete(log.get("_id"))}
    >
      Delete
    </a>
  </div>
  )
}


class DeleteConfirmation extends React.PureComponent {
  handleDelete(key) {
    console.log("key", key);
    this.props.onDelete(key);
    this.props.hideDialog();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal show onHide={() => this.props.hideDialog()} className="md-box">
        <h1>Are you sure want to delete?</h1>
          <button
            onClick={() => this.handleDelete(this.props.logKey)}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first component remove `(key)` in onDelete.

```
 <DeleteConfirmation
      hideDialog={this.props.hideDialog}
      logKey={key}
      onDelete={this.props.deleteLog(key)} //here
    />
```

Just `onDelete={this.props.deleteLog}` You call this action, instead of sending ref to it.